# How to INTERACT between a program on the server and the user via a web page REAL-TIME

Tags: python, ajax, cgi, subprocess, pipe

Let me start with an example:
There is a c++ program which can be run on my server, the program is named "Guess the Number" which means every time it runs,

1. first it will generate an integer between 1 and 100 randomly.
2. then i need the user to guess a number and pass it to me though a web page, form or something.
3. now i want pass the number to the program and then the program will tell me whether it's bigger or smaller.
4. then i put the information on the web page to let the user know and then make his next guess.

i am able to write the program. and i know how pass the first argument and give back the information, but don't know how to interact in the next steps. i.e.

**How to pass the arguments to the program REAL-TIME and get the output?**

to make this more clearly:

1. i use `subprocess` in `python` to run the program with the **first argument** and get the output.
2. the c++ program use std inputs and outputs, like `while (!check(x)) scanf("%d",&x);`, and in `check(int x)`, i use `if (x>rand_num) printf("too big\n");` to output.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at HTML5 sockets. Leaving this as a comment because I don't really know them in detail.

Comment: I'm not getting the real time focus of this question?

Comment: @Steve-o i mean, the user give a number, the webpage shows a piece of information, the user give a number again, the webpage shows a another piece of information correspondingly, goes on the loop....

Comment: Can't you just use plain good Python and forget about subprocess?

Comment: The expression "real-time" normally refers to the absence of delay between an action and its effect, which is something you simply can't have over the internet, given that your code is not in control of the latency of the web (all the computers that will re-route your packets). What you are really looking for is how to make the client and the server communicate asynchronously (in the background). The most common way to achieve it is using a technique called AJAX (asynchronous JavaScript and XML). You can find tons of info by googling it. HTH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved this problem in this way:

1. Use [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) to interact with that program.
2. Use [unbuffer](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) to get the output immediately.

Here is an example

```
import pexpect

p = pexpect.spawn('unbuffer',['-p','./guess'])
l = 1
r = 100
m = 0
while (p.isalive()):
    p.expect('')
    p.expect(p.buffer[-1])
    print p.before
    print m
    if (p.before.find('small')>0):
        l = m
    elif (p.before.find('big')>0):
        r = m
    m = (l+r)/2;
    p.sendline(str(m))
print p.buffer
print 'Program ended!'
```

and the guess.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    srand(int(time(0)));
    int n = (rand() % 100) + 1;
    int x;
    printf("The number you are to guess is between 1 and 100.\n");
    do{
        scanf("%d",&x);
        if (x<n) printf("Too small!\n");
            else if (x>n) printf("Too big!\n");
    }   while (x!=n);
    printf("You got it!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like a homework question, but even with this list, you have a lot of work ahead of you for a dubious reward, so here we go.

- Your C++ program should listen on a socket
- Your python program needs to listen on a web socket, and also have a connection open to the C++ program through the C++ socket.
- I'd suggest something like web.py for your web framework
- Your web.py program is going to accept XMLHTTP Requests at a URL
- your web page is going to submit requests through that XMLHTTP request, and send results back into the web page.

An easy way to do this on the frontend is to you jquery ajax commands; they will hit your web.py URL, which will validate the input, call a function to send it off to the C++ socket, get a response and send it back as a response to your jquery request.

Good luck.

Comment: my bad, the c++ program must use std input and output.